# Building a graph by a dynamic nested dictionary with a file in Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, tree

I build a big nested dictionary which represents a "forest", meaning a collection of trees by using the following code:

```
def create_forest(edges):
    """Given a list of edges [child, parent], return trees. """
    trees = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for child, parent in edges:
        trees[parent][child] = trees[child]
    # Find roots
    children, parents = zip(*edges)
    roots = set(parents).difference(children)
    return {root: trees[root] for root in roots}
```

This piece builds a graph by returning a dictionary. I would like to build the same kind of graph is the same way (to get a forest) but I want to use a file in the disk instead of keeping the dictionary in the memory. 
Is there any way to build the forest in a file instead in a dictionary? If it is possible to dump the file's content afterwards to a dictionary it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

That depends if all the values in the forest are json serializeable you can use `json.load` and `json.dump` to load the structure from file and to dump it to file like so:

```
import json

forest = {
    "ancestro1": {
        "ancestor2":
            {
            "ancestror3": 123,
             "ancestor4":  654,
                "ancestor5": True}
    },
        "ancestor6":None
}


with open("file.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(forest,f)

with open("file.json","r") as f:
    forest = json.load(f)
print(forest)
```

Output:

`{'ancestro1': {'ancestor2': {'ancestror3': 123, 'ancestor4': 654, 'ancestor5': True}}, 'ancestor6': None}`

File contens:

`{"ancestro1": {"ancestor2": {"ancestror3": 123, "ancestor4": 654, "ancestor5": true}}, "ancestor6": null}`

Comment: I want to build the forest dynamically in a file not dump a ready forest

Comment: Then you would need to create some custom class, which would first read a state from file and then dynamically modify the file inline. And it is starting to sound like a database engine so why not use a database? I doubt you get similar  efficiency with your own implementation. Inline changes to large files can easily be a bottleneck